# Процент покрытия кода юнит-тестами

Tags: c#, .net, тестирование, юнит-тесты

Есть ли какой нибудь способ точно оценить процент кода, покрытого юнит-тестами (nunit)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для тестов в Visual Studio есть встроенные средства, позволяющие считать покрытие. Нужно

1. Включить расчет покрытия: `Test > Edit Test Run Configurations > Your Test Configuration`, далее Code Coverage, и выбрать сборку для тестирования.
2. Прогнать тесты.
3. Правый клик по тестам, и вызов Code Coverage Results.

В итоге вы увидите статистику по процентам

- Not Covered Blocks
- Not Covered Blocks %
- Covered Blocks
- Covered Blocks %

Не проверял, как это соотносится с nUnit. Еще есть сторонние стредства, например, [nCover](http://www.ncover.com/), [partCover](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partcover/), [openCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover).